# Broken index in Drupal 7 site

Tags: drupal-7

I added a field to a Drupal view sort (level 2) and it didn't sort. I got a missing index message when I saved the view. When I enabled the syslog module to see if I could find the problem  the recent log messages does not appear in the menu nor if I try to go directly to the page. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I seem to have fixed by installing and using db_maintenance module and running cron a few times. Now I can see the log messages etc and the view is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by installing and using db_maintenance module then running cron a few times.